# LNK2005 and LNK1169 while programing signal in QT

Tags: c++, qt, lnk2005

While I've been programing a connection between 2 `QThread` in **QT**. First is `QMainWindow` and second is my own class `DB`, which base on `QThread`, becouse I'd like don't to stop **GUI** thread during downloading data from data base server. But when I've add `signals` to my new class, everything goes wrong. I've recieved errors:

**ERRORS**

```
Error   LNK2005 "public: void __cdecl DB::statusChanged(void)" (?statusChanged@DB@@QEAAXXZ) already defined in mocs_compilation.cpp.obj 
Error   LNK2005 "public: void __cdecl DB::dataDownloaded(void)" (?dataDownloaded@DB@@QEAAXXZ) already defined in mocs_compilation.cpp.obj     
Error   LNK1169 one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

A minute ago every thing is ok with the code, but when I add signals to the files, program stop working.

**CODE**

DB.h

```
#ifndef DB_H
#define DB_H

#include <qthread.h>
class patient;

class DB: public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
//--------------------
//CONSTRUCTORS AND DESTRUCTORS
//--------------------
public:
    DB();
    DB(std::vector<patient> *list);
    ~DB();
//--------------------
//SLOTS AND SIGNALS
//--------------------
signals:
    void statusChanged();
    void dataDownloaded();
private:
    std::vector<patient> *listOfPatients;
//--------------------
//METHODS
//--------------------
public:
    void run();
    DB& operator=(const DB& source);
};
#endif  //DB_H
```

DB.cpp

```
#include "DB.h"
#include "patient.h"

//--------------------
//CONSTRUCTORS AND DESTRUCTORS
//--------------------
DB::DB()
{
    listOfPatients = nullptr;
}
DB::DB(std::vector<patient> *list)
{
    listOfPatients = list;
}
DB::~DB()
{
}
//--------------------
//SIGNAL AND SLOTS
//--------------------
void statusChanged()
{
}
void dataDownloaded()
{
}
//--------------------
//METHODS
//--------------------
void DB::run()
{
    //import data from DB - to be implement
    emit dataDownloaded();
}

DB& DB::operator=(const DB &source)
{
    this->listOfPatients = source.listOfPatients;
    return *this;
}
```

Have you got any ideas what was wrong?

Answer (score -2):

The problem was that I've tried to define the signals, which was define in QT automaticly. I don't know that but one comment motivate me to check what happand when I delete definition of my signals in `DB.cpp` and this was the clue of the problem.

So the correct `DB.cpp` file was:

```
#include "DB.h"
#include "patient.h"

//--------------------
//CONSTRUCTORS AND DESTRUCTORS
//--------------------
DB::DB()
{
    listOfPatients = nullptr;
}
DB::DB(std::vector<patient> *list)
{
    listOfPatients = list;
}
DB::~DB()
{
}
//--------------------
//SIGNAL AND SLOTS
//--------------------

//NO SIGNAL DEFINITION THERE

//--------------------
//METHODS
//--------------------
void DB::run()
{
    //import data from DB - to be implement
    emit dataDownloaded();
}

DB& DB::operator=(const DB &source)
{
    this->listOfPatients = source.listOfPatients;
    return *this;
}
```